# How to replace some encoded character in a query string before Laravel create a Request instance?

Tags: laravel, url

When the query string separator `&` is encoded with its corresponding value `%26`, the request cannot extract the query parameters correctly.

On my web application, I do not encode this character and I have no controls on how it's structured before hitting my API.

I did a debug trace of the Request object in the controller method and this URL `my.api.com/api/productcategory/catalogue?sort_by%5bcountry.name_en%5d=asc&sort_by%5bproductbrand.name%5d=asc&sort_by%5bproduct.name%5d=asc&sort_by%5bvintage.vintage%5d=asc&per_page=25&page=1&lang=en` returns the correct following query parameters:

```
query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#60 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "sort_by" => array:4 [▶]
      "per_page" => "25"
      "page" => "1"
      "lang" => "en"
    ]
  }
```

On the other hand, when the `&` is encoded as in this URL `my.api.com/api/productcategory/catalogue?sort_by%5bcountry.name_en%5d=asc%26sort_by%5bproductbrand.name%5d=asc%26sort_by%5bproduct.name%5d=asc%26sort_by%5bvintage.vintage%5d=asc%26per_page=25%26page=1%26lang=en`, the query parameter are wrongly  extracted like this:

```
query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#60 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "sort_by" => array:1 [▼
        "country.name_en" => "asc&sort_by[productbrand.name]=asc&sort_by[product.name]=asc&sort_by[vintage.vintage]=asc&per_page=25&page=1&lang=en"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Is there a way to intercept the query and do a `str_replace('%26', '&', $theQuery)` before it gets process by the Request object?

I'm Using Laravel 6.2 with PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Your client is broken and should be sending the correct request. If they aren't going to do that, rewriting at the web server level would probably be more performant than doing it in middleware.

Comment: @miken32, My client site is not broken.  The link was issued properly but most probably traveled from one system to another (mail server, firewall, gateway, ...) and was encoded for whatever reason. Then the user used it to request the given information.  I am just baffled Laravel cannot detect the encoded '&' in the query string and I have to do the work for it.

Comment: The entire point of the client encoding things in URLs is so they *aren't* treated specially by the server. Your solution may cause problems in the case where the URL contains values that need to be escaped; e.g. a search for "macaroni & cheese."

Comment: You got a point on that one.  Good catch!  Then I have to figure out how the query parameter separator got somewhat encoded - which might be a daunting task.

Answer (score 1):

As per Andrew suggestion, here is the solution using a Middleware, where it is called for each API routes.

```
class URLMonitorMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Parse the full URL and return its components
        $parsedUrl = parse_url($request->fullUrl());
        // There may not always be a query string...!
        if (isset($parsedUrl['query'])) {
            // Decode the query
            $decodedQuery = urldecode($parsedUrl['query']);
            // Parses the query into variables
            parse_str($decodedQuery, $query);
            // Replaces the current parameters with the query set.
            $request->replace($query);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for middleware in this situation. It allows you to manage requests before they enter the application. You can manipulate the request object. Middleware can be applied to every single route globally or selectively used on certain routes only.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
 
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 
class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Perform action
 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#before-after-middleware)

When dealing with the request object, Laravel has built in methods for overwriting attributes. You can access specific attributes with:

```
$data = $request->all();
// $data['sort_by']
```

But in your case you can access the url and modify it with:

```
$request->fullUrl()
```

[Accessing the request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#accessing-the-request)

Comment: Indeed a good woraround - a bit kacky but will do the job.  Thx for the suggestion.